# usage of "pfeifend" in the expression "der Mann wieder glücklich pfeifend den Weg entlang ging"

Tags: grammar-identification

I'm self studying German these days and learning grammar too.
In the sentence below, what's the grammatical form of `pfeifend`?
Is it something like present/past participle usage in English?
(like `whistling` as in `Whistling his favorite song, He went along the street`)

```
    Sie lachten beide zusammen und beobachteten, wie der Mann wieder glücklich pfeifend den Weg entlang ging.
==>  
    They both laughed together and watched the man whistling happily back down the path.
```

Comment: "pfeifend" = "whistling". "The man went, happily whistling again, along the path".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pfeifend` is the participle of `pfeifen`, that's true.

The participle describes the action of somebody while not addressing him directly like you would do in English.

And here's another style thing with your sentence: Although it's not incorrect to write `Sie lachten beide zusammen`, I wouldn't recommend it. `Sie lachten zusammen` or `Sie lachten beide` works just fine. To a native German-speaker, it sounds awkward if you use `beide` and `zusammen` in the same context.

Comment: Does it *sound awkward* if you use **beide zusammen**? Don't think so. Think about "Sie fuhren beide mit dem Auto weg" vs. "Sie fuhren beide zusammen mit dem Auto weg"

Comment: Zum Thema _beide_ versus _die beiden_ oder _beide zusammen_ siehe http://isabelbogdan.de/2012/02/17/tante-isas-kleine-deutschstunde-beide-die-beiden/.

Answer (score 1):

You were close. "Pfeifend" is "Partizip Präsens" (present participle) of "pfeifen".
In general, you obtain the "Partizip Präsens" by adding a "d" to the infinitive. As in English, you can use it like an adjective or an adverb. Note that you cannot use the "Partizip Präsens" like a "gerund" in German.
 In your example, "Pfeifend" is used as an adverb. Your translation misses a translation of the word "ging". I see no way to keep the "adverb" character of the participle and would say:

"... whistling happily and going back down the path. "

Comment: The two exceptions for building the *Partizip Präsens* are *sein* → *seiend* and *tun* → *tuend*.

Comment: thanks, that helps. and I was aware the translation `whistle down (a road)` includes the meaning of `gehn`. (I selected the other answer just because it was the first. sorry for that..)